# How to test if a related column is neither empty nor blank in dax?

Tags: powerbi, dax

all-- New to Dax, and trying to figure out what's wrong with this formula. I've already established a connection between the three tables All_Combined_Terms_Bb_Course_ID, GR, and UG. I want to create a column that returns "Graduate Courses" if catalog number is greater than or equal to 500 AND if GR[Area] is neither blank nor empty, on the one hand, and "Undergraduate Courses" if catalog number is less than 500 AND if UG[Area] is neither blank nor empty. If neither of these are true, then return "Neither". Here's what I have--I'm sorry I cannot provide a minimum reproducible code bit with data!

```
GR or UG = IF(
    AND(All_Combined_Terms_Bb_Course_ID[Catalog Number] >= 500, IF(
        OR(NOT(ISBLANK(RELATED(GR[AREA]))),NOT(ISEMPTY(RELATED(GR[AREA])))),"Graduate Courses", 
        IF(
        AND(All_Combined_Terms_Bb_Course_ID[Catalog Number] < 500,
            IF(OR(NOT(ISBLANK(RELATED(UG[AREA]))),(NOT(ISEMPTY(RELATED(UG[AREA]))))),"Undergraduate Courses",
            "Neither"
))
```

I know that nesting is often a problem, and that's probable here, too--but I'm getting an error I don't really understand how to deal with, too: "Parameter is not of the correct type" at the (not(isblank(related(xx[xxxx])))) sections.

I'm trying to create the Dax formula in Power BI.

Answer (score 0):

Try to substitute this:

```
(NOT(ISEMPTY(RELATED(UG[AREA])))))
```

with this:

```
(NOT(ISEMPTY(RELATED(UG[AREA]))))
```